# Sending php json down to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JSON object array that is created in PHP that I need to be able to send down to javascript so that javascript can sort through the JSON using JSON.parse

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have this endpoint that produces that JSON data : sample.com/json.php
In your json.php

```
<?php
   echo json_encode($your_json_variable);
?>
```

And in your script, using Jquery AJAX :

```
$.getJSON('sample.com/json.php', function(data){

    $.each(data, function(k,v){
     console.log(v);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

It actually depends on how you want to get it with javascript. If you will get it with ajax you can use it like below to write it out.

```
<%php echo json_encode($your_json_data);%>
```

If your javascript is on same file as your json array is than

```
<script language="javascript">
 var myJSJson = <%php echo json_encode($json_data)%>;
</script>
```

Would do the trick.